# Reduce power consumption script

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, pi-zero, raspi-config, power-management

I have read on this blog that you can reduce power consumption:

https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/raspberry-pi-zero-conserve-energy

By disabling the HDMI port.

He says that I should add this line:

`/usr/bin/tvservice -o`

to `/etc/rc.local`

But I don't know where and how, my /etc/rc.local file is like this:

```
_IP= || true
if [ "" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" ""
fi

# disable console blanking on PiTFT
sudo sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -blank 0 >/dev/tty0"





exit 0
```

Where to add this line, and would it work?

Comment: Try adding t after sudo sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -blank 0 >/dev/tty0" and before exit 0

Comment: @SteveRobillard should I just add it like that, or should I add `sudo` prefix before it as well?

Comment: did the tutorial have sudo? if not then no.

Comment: The `sudo` in the previous line is also redundant - `/etc/rc.local` is executed by/as root (or possibly the kernel) before other users are even considered... OTOH `/etc/local` is an SysV `init` thing - does it still get considered/run if `systemd` is run as the first process as "Jessie" and later ("Stretch" is out on Debian has it made it to Raspbian yet?) uses that by default - although if you are a SysV `init` hold-out like me you may not know/care...! 8-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
/usr/bin/tvservice -o
```

between these two lines:

```
sudo sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -blank 0 >/dev/tty0"

exit 0
```

To reenable HDMI change this line:

```
/usr/bin/tvservice -o
```

to

```
/usr/bin/tvservice -p
```

**Note:** for these lines to take effect will require a reboot.